# Is something wrong with stpncpy() here?

Tags: c++, c

This is an existing code which finds a relative path corresponds to parent path. It has been working as expected on platforms except on SUSE 12 with GCC 4.7.
**I've mentioned one of the wrong output and expected in the comments.** 
**I am trying to understand why does this happen ?** **What is wrong with this code ?** 
Both the child and parent strings end with NUL character. The only other thing I see is that source and destination are passed from the same memory location in other words we we are trying to update the value of same memory location. 
Is that the real problem ?

```
//child = /dev/shm/4/tmp/backup/datadir/performance_schema/events_stages_summary_by_account_by_event_name.frm 
//parent =  /dev/shm/4/tmp/backup

char* get_relative_path(char *child, const char *parent)
{
    char* start= child;
    static char dot[] = "." ;

    ....
    ....

    /* Check if child = parent + "/" + ....  */
    if (strstr(child, parent) == child)
    {
        int parent_len= strlen(parent);

        /* parent path may or may not have the "/" suffix. check for both. */
        if (parent[parent_len-1] == FN_LIBCHAR ||
            child[parent_len] == FN_LIBCHAR)
        {
            child+= parent_len;
            while (*child && *child == FN_LIBCHAR)
                child++;
            if (*child == 0)
                return dot;
        }
    }
   // At this point the value of 
   // start = /dev/shm/4/tmp/backup/datadir/performance_schema/events_stages_summary_by_account_by_event_name.frm 
   // child = datadir/performance_schema/events_stages_summary_by_account_by_event_name.frm

    if(start != child)
    {
        stpncpy(start, child, PATH_MAX);
    }

   // At this point  expected value of  start = datadir/performance_schema/events_stages_summary_by_account_by_event_name.frm
   // But actual value of start =  datadir/performance_schenamevents_stages_summary_by_account_by_event_name.frm 

   return start;
}
```

Comment: Man page of stpncpy says the strings may **not** overlap. You could solve it by having a function that starts backwards and thus will not read from an already written location. I don't know if this is the actual problem from looking at this real quick but it's one potential problem.

Comment: Ok ... jite and  @mch  pointed out the same problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the Man Page of [`stpncpy`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/stpncpy.3.html): `The strings may not overlap.`

So you should use [`memmove`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memmove.3.html), otherwise the behaviour is undefined.

`stpncpy(start, child, PATH_MAX);` should be
`memmove(start, child, PATH_MAX > strlen(child) + 1? strlen(child) + 1: PATH_MAX);`

You should also bear in mind that `stpncpy` is very inefficient if you are using small strings on large arrays, because it will write `n` characters every time. In your case it would write around 4000 `'\0'` after your string.
The Man Page says

> Exactly n characters are written at dest.
>       If the length strlen(src) is smaller than n, the remaining characters
>       in the array pointed to by dest are filled with null bytes ('\0')

Comment: Code mentioned above had been working fine for years  but suddenly we starts seeing this problem.  hmm..but I see your point **may**  seems culprit in the sentence  `The string may not overlap` mentioned on man page.

Comment: let me try out your solution once that works I shall mark it as an answer.  So the actual answer to my question is that  usage of stpncpy(), strcpy() , strncpy()  is not safe if the memory overlaps.

Comment: Using this function on overlapping strings may lead to undefined behavior – which includes both "works as expected" as well as "... except here". Whether it works or not depends on the implementation of the function; and implementations may differ across libraries for different compilers and/or platforms.